# Bringing value of hyperlink from jsp page to servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, hyperlink

I have a jsp page which displays a list of hyperlinks using a for loop. I want to bring the value of the hyperlink (the list of hyperlinks have different values as they are from an arraylist) across to my servlet, so that the values of each hyperlink will be distinct.

I tried using request.getSession.setAttribute("value",list.get(0)) but I realised that it would only take the last value in the list so the value being brought across remains the same for all hyperlinks.

Any advice on that?

My code is as below.

```
 <% List<ArrayList> transactions = (List<ArrayList>) request.getAttribute("transactions");
     int count = 0;         
     for (Object o : transactions) 
     {
       count++;
       String status;
       ArrayList list = (ArrayList) o;               
  %>

     <a href="anotherjsppage"><%=list.get(0) //how to bring this value to servlet%></a><br>
     <%=list.get(1) //some other value to be displayed%><br>
     <%
     }
     %>
```

Comment: Use that list.get(0) as a value in the anchor tag and in the Servlet you can access it using request.getParameter() method.

Comment: So in that case does it mean that I have to do this? <a href="anotherjsppage?value=list.get(0)"> <%=list.get(0)%></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like..

```
<a href="anotherjsppage"><%=list.get(0) //how to bring this value to servlet%></a> 
<input type="hidden" value=<%=list.get(0)%> name="hi"/>
```

and then use this hidden input and get value by

```
 request.getParameter("hi");
```

in servlet.

Comment: But i would get an error where i do the following way. it says "Attribute ""hi"" is not serializable as XML 1.0....
Attribute ""hi"" not allowed on element "input" at this point.
Element-specific attributes for element 'input':
Global attributes
'accept'
'alt'
'autocomplete'
'autofocus'
'checked'
'disabled'
'for..."

Comment: yupp after clicking on the link to another jsp page, the value of list.get(0) will be brought over to the servlet and based on the value the other jsp page will display the other values accordingly...

Comment: Okay now i get it, in this scenario you can append the value to the url  href="anotherjsppage?hi=<%=list.get(0)%>"